# GitHub reusable workflows secrets vs passing as input for composite actions

Tags: github, github-actions

What's the difference between how secrets are handled between a composite action and a reusable workflow?

For instance, for an action, we could pass a secret via the input as so

```
name: Composite Action

description: 'test'

inputs:
  token:
    description: 'A Github PAT'
    required: true
```

but for a reusable workflow, we need to use `secrets` as opposed to `inputs`

```
name: Reusable Workflow

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      ...
    secrets:
      token:
        required: true
```

I have tried passing in secrets to `inputs` itself, but it doesn't work, so is this a design choice intended to make secrets more explicit? I am not sure what other benefits there are because I don't think there's a way to centralize secrets.

I.e. suppose we have X repos calling a single reusable workflow, then:

- X repos each have their own secrets and each pass it to the reusable workflow
- X repos could use an organizational secret to reduce the # of secrets going around, but still need to pass it to the reusable workflow.

Comment: You may use [`secrets: inherit`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#passing-inputs-and-secrets-to-a-reusable-workflow).

Comment: From what I understand, there is no possibility to pass arbitrary secrets into a reusable workflow, which I consider a major limitation of reusable workflows. The fact that all secrets need to be known in advance greatly limits potential solutions and the ability to pass own values to actions that can be embedded in a reusable workflow. `secret:inherit` does not solve the problem at all, because as I mentioned, all secrets to be used must be specified in advance.